# is Phone Gap capable of converting a php web app into an iphone/android app?

Tags: javascript, iphone, android, html, cordova

Does anyone use PhoneGap?

I have a php app which uses ajax to receive json data. This technology called PhoneGap http://www.phonegap.com/, 
is it able to convert my php app into an iphone/android app?

I know that if it is simply a javascript / html / css app that does not require server side technologies Phone Gap is capable.

However I definitely require the internet access and ajax connection to online web services.

Comment: Lots of people here develop for PhoneGap. I tagged your question with `phonegap`. Click the tag to see the many questions and how people are using it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does anyone use PhoneGap?

Yes.

> is it able to convert my php app into an iphone/android app?

PhoneGap does not "convert" anything. *You* can convert your "php app into an iphone/android app", and PhoneGap might be part of your solution.

You would start by getting rid of all the "php" -- if your "app" can run purely in a browser using local storage, it will almost assuredly work with PhoneGap. PhoneGap also supplies some PhoneGap-specific JavaScript APIs, which you may or may not need.

> However I definitely require the internet access and ajax connection to online web services.

PhoneGap neither helps nor hurts here. PhoneGap wraps around the Android `WebView` widget, which is itself based on WebKit, the same rendering engine used by Chrome, Safari, etc. If, after you get rid of your "php", your "app" works in Safari and Chome, it should work as "an iphone/android app" with PhoneGap, with some adjustment to your HTML/CSS/JS to deal with smaller screen sizes, touchscreens, etc.