# Convert Existing PHP/MYSQL/ website to Native IOS/Android Apps

Tags: php, android, mysql, ios, native

Weeks of searching and worked on a few guides to convert my existing hosted PHP/MYSQL website to Native IOS/Android Apps. So far no good result. Tried Phonegap and Cordova too. Searches from the past years back to 2009 stated it is not possible. Is it possible now? Can share a complete guide or e-book for it? The app will be just a direct link to my php website. The app is actually acting like a browser. This is my very first app.

http://tech.sarathdr.com/featured/steps-to-convert-a-web-app-into-android-phonegap-app/

http://antonylees.blogspot.sg/2013/02/launch-website-as-mobile-app-using.html

Comment: Just so you know, simply wrapping a website in an app will not get you past Apple's review process.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

May be you should look at `webview`.. its a widget which **wraps your webapp to android webview**, basically It means your **webapp will open in a browser** but it will give **look and feel like an mobile app** .

here are some tutorials and information about `webview` from `android-sdk` and `xda-developers`

> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html
>
> http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2308089
>
> http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html

And Also check this answer too,

> [is Phone Gap capable of converting a php web app into an iphone/android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6634933/is-phone-gap-capable-of-converting-a-php-web-app-into-an-iphone-android-app)..
>   You can later on, add some features to the application by adding geolocation features for example. Here is an example using Apache Cordova 
>   https://auth0.com/blog/converting-your-web-app-to-mobile/

let me know if you want any further guidance......

Comment: thanks... i will try work around with webview and update again.. thanks again! I will get all the necessary to setup android development environment

Comment: @Fxster welcome... If you liked my answer than please +1 and accept as correct.. :)

Comment: from the phone gap thread above.. i dont think my website can turned into html.... i need alot of database access which html cant process. A simple form registration or login also have to go through mysql