# Converting an Web Application into an Android APP

Tags: php, android, mysql, software-design

This question might have been asked a number of times earlier like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22215671/convert-existing-php-mysql-website-to-native-ios-android-apps). However, this did not answer my question(s). So I am posting again.

I have developed an Web Management Software. It is built using PHP/HTML/MySQL. The tool has a number of features like user management, signup forms, report generation etc. Now, I intend to get an Android App developed. I am not an expert at Android Development.

1. I am planning to build a native Android APP and not use ´webview´ library.
2. How do I get the Android App developed ? Do I need to make any changes on the server side for this ?
3. Do I need to build API and the Android APP would make `httprequest` ?
4. I am not keen on the solution proposed by [Phonegap](http://www.phonegap.com)
5. Are there any other approaches which I might have to consider ?

I am sure, this could be very basic question for experts working in Android. It is just that, I have never seriously worked with Android. Sorry for my ignorance, though.

Comment: if you are looking for a native app then I would suggest to develop the android client and you can connect to your mysql database using php which is very much supported with android. Believe me it's easy and can be done within 1-2 weeks time..what's the idea for your app because you cannot run a mobile app like a web app on a browser otherwise use a phone browser?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to develop a APP for Android you have to write it in Java if you not want to use Phonegap.
You can use the Android SDK and the Eclipse version. (There is a Eclipse version made for that)
But if you want to build your Project you already developed you can use Cordova, it's a similar Project to Phonegap, but free to use.
Then you have to run a Service on your Server for all Funktions.
You can use Javascript there to connect.